# Cannot import contacts from vcf file with images on Android 4.4.4

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I'm creating a vcf file manually by adding details like phone, email and photo. I am following the vcf format 3.0

```
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(PATH, true);
        for (VCard vcard : vcards) {
            StringBuilder contactsList = new StringBuilder(); 
            String name = vcard.getFormattedName().getValue();


            contactsList.append("BEGIN:VCARD\r\n");
            contactsList.append("VERSION:3.0\r\n");
            contactsList.append("N:" + name + "\r\n");
            contactsList.append("TEL;TYPE=WORK,VOICE:" + vcard.getTelephoneNumbers().getText() + "\r\n");

                contactsList.append("EMAIL;TYPE=PREF,INTERNET:" + vcard.getEmails().getValue() + "\r\n");

                String ctype=photoList.get(0).getContentType().toString();
                byte[] data = photoList.get(0).getData();
                String strdata = new String(data,"UTF-8");
                contactsList.append("PHOTO;ENCODING=B;TYPE=JPEG:" + vcard.getPhotos().get(0) +"\r\n");
                contactsList.append("END:VCARD\r\n");

            fileOutputStream.write(contactsList.toString().getBytes());

        } 

        fileOutputStream.close();
        File contactFile = new File(FILES_PATH);

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(contactFile), "text/x-vcard");
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);

    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Even when I try to import manually in Android 4.4.4 device, it imports without images, but Android 5.0 works.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions, and this is not a question. Beyond that, it is up to the implementer of the activity that handles your `Intent` to determine what to do with the `Intent` data. There is no requirement that every such activity offer support for every element of a vCard. Bear in mind that there are any number of apps that a user could have -- preinstalled or installed by the user -- that could respond to your requested `Intent` structure, and any of them can do whatever they want, differently from any other such app.

Comment: This code as it is works on every Android version except 4.4.4 Intent is automatically handled by the Contacts app (installed by default) and I am sure my device has one. Unfortunately, this code imports contacts but not the images from vcf file. 
This question is to ask if anybody encountered this type of behavior and the solution

Comment: Its very strange that it imports images only if the vcf file has 1 contact.

Comment: "This code as it is works on every Android version except 4.4.4" -- for the devices that you tested. "Intent is automatically handled by the Contacts app" -- first, that is true only on devices where the user has not installed other apps that have activities with an equivalent `<intent-filter>`. Second, there are many implementations of "the Contacts app", as it is routinely altered by device manufacturers. You have tested a couple of device models out of thousands.